# segment does not contain sync frame

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg, sync

Whenever I split a video using Apple's `mediafilesegmenter`, using the following command: `medifilesegmenter video.ts -t 10`. I get the following error for each segment except the first:

```
segment does not contain sync frame
```

Before splitting I've converted the .MP4 version to a .TS with the following command:

```
avconv -y -i video.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -b 64k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 0 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 64k -bufsize 64k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 30 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 640:480 -g 30 -async 2 sample_64.ts
```

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs?